# Display icon and text at top and bottom position

Tags: html, css

I am working on css to display icon and text at top and bottom position like this icon.

[image: icon]

I am tried so far these codes. I dont know much about front end part. I can do only float or margin left and right only.

Can anybody help me how can I fix this.

```css
.sub-menu {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.sub-menu .menu-title {
  clear: both;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sub-menu">
  <img src="css/images/nearby.png">
  <span class="menu-title">NEARBY</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try with the following CSS code:

```css
.sub-menu {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

.sub-menu .menu-title {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sub-menu">
  <img src="css/images/nearby.png">
  <span class="menu-title">NEARBY</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Chaska

Answer (score 4):

Try using the below snippet to make it work. Use Display:flex.

```css
.sub-menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
}

.sub-menu .menu-title {}
```

```html
<div class="sub-menu">
  <img src="css/images/nearby.png">
  <p class="menu-title">NEARBY</p>
</div>
```